# Trouble Adding SQLite Reference in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, sqlite, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to add System.Data.SQLite to my References in Visual Studio 2015. I've right-clicked on References, and selected "Manage NuGet Packages", where I've found System.Data.SQLite and installed it into my project. It successfully installs and then shows up in my list of References, but when I type `using System.Data.SQLite;` into my code, intellisense doesn't recognize it. I get an error when I compile saying 'SQLite' does not exist in the namespace `System.Data`. I've searched my entire hardrive and the file System.Data.SQLite.dll doesn't exist anywhere. What am I missing here? Did Visual Studio install it or not?

Comment: well... yeah. me too.
I experiencing the same here with vstudio 2015.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to part of the problem by going to C # (was not critical of the choice of language). I found an article at this link. To sum up, you need to download the library with SQLite site for the desired bit and throw in the bin folder to the list of libraries (do not forget to link the project to the "sqlite3.dll" this library). Just put in NuGet SQLite.Net-PCL expansion (by the way, in C ++ for some reason do not connect, can not be supported for C ++). Sample code to work with SQLite large. All have the link above. https://www.sqlite.org/cintro.html